# Install valgrind on ubi8-minimal docker image

Tags: docker, valgrind

I want to install valgrind on a docker container based on ubi-8 minimal image. The problem is the tool doesn't seem to be available in any packages on the microdnf repository. I tried with gcc-toolset-11-valgrind, gcc-toolset-11-gcc-11, gcc-toolset-11-gcc-c++, gcc-toolset-11-runtime, etc to see if the tool is available in any package. There should be a package available for normal rpm: gcc-toolset-11-perftools, but it isn't available.
I also tried to download valgrind by hand and execute from a volume but the dependencies are not available. Is there a easier way to get running valgrind on a ubi8-minimal docker container?

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to run Valgrind in docker rather than on a real OS install?

Comment: Yes, the application I want to analyze is already dockerized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rpm in combination with already download packages I finally managed to install valgrind, the process was:

1. download valgrind package and dependencies with yum in the host machine

   `yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=./valgrindDownload gcc-toolset-11-valgrind`
2. Find out missing dependencies (gcc-toolset-11-runtime-11, and perl)
3. Install local packages using rpm:

   `rpm --install ./valgrindDownload/gcc-toolset-11-valgrind-3.17.0-6.el8.x86_64.rpm`
4. Find out valgrind instalation directory
   In my case was under /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/bin/valgrind

   Finally run the full command:
   `` sudo docker run -v `pwd`:/home/<container-dir> <docker-image>:<version> /bin/bash -c  "microdnf install gcc-toolset-11-runtime-11.1-1.el8.x86_64 &&  microdnf install perl-5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64 &&  rpm --install ./valgrindDownload/gcc-toolset-11-valgrind-3.17.0-6.el8.x86_64.rpm &&  /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/root/usr/bin/valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out.txt command <arguments>" ``

Doing so, the valgrind output gets redirected to valgrind-out.txt